# java httpclient detect server disconnect

Tags: java, httpclient

I'm doing a GET request with the apache HttpClient. Is there a way to detect when the server disconnects while reading from the InputStream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EOS on the input stream (read() returning -1, readLine() returning null, readXXX() throwing EOFException for any other XXX) is the primary mechanism, otherwise an IOException, typically 'connection reset'. Very rarely you may see a SocketException. If you are using read timeouts, a SocketTimeoutException.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, check out the [Exception Handling section](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d4e258) of the docs.